# Need to delete complete row if paranoid in true in Node js Express Js Sequelize Postgres

Tags: postgresql, express, sequelize.js

Need to delete a complete row from Postgres if using paranoid is true, in Node JS, Express JS, Sequelize JS

Comment: paranoid is for soft delete in sequelize ORM

Comment: If `paranoid === true`, then the row will not be deleted. A `deletedAt` attribute will be added. http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-definition.html

Answer (score 0):

Hey man i have the answer here. I know you have waited too long for that answer, but now I`ve found it!

You just need to use

```
{
  force: true
}
```

[https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/paranoid/#:~:text=If%20you%20really,WHERE%20%22id%22%20%3D%201](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/paranoid/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20really,WHERE%20%22id%22%20%3D%201)

Enjoy!